# Storing Large Integers/Values in an Embedded System

Tags: c, embedded, avr, avr-gcc

I'm developing a embedded system that can test a large numbers of wires (upto 360) - essentially a continuity checking system. The system works by clocking in a test vector and reading the output from the other end. The output is then compared with a stored result (which would be on an SD Card) that tells what the output *should* have been. The test-vectors are just a walking ones so there's no need to store them anywhere. The process would be a bit like follows:

1. Clock out test-vector (walking ones)
2. Read in output test-vector.
3. Read corresponding output test-vector from SD Card which tells what the output vector should be.
4. Compare the test-vectors from step 2 and 3.
5. Note down the errors/faults in a separate array.
6. Continue back to step 1 unless all wires are checked.
7. Output the errors/faults to the LCD.

My hardware consists of a large shift register thats clocked into the AVR microcontroller. For every test vector (which would also be 360 bits), I will need to read in 360 bits. So, for 360 wires the total amount of data would be 360*360 = 16kB or so. I already know I cannot do this in one pass (i.e. read the entire data and then compare), so it will have to be test-vector by test-vector.

As there are no inherent types that can hold such large numbers, I intend to use a bit-array of length 360 bit. **Now, my question is, how should I store this bit array in a txt file?**

One way is to store raw values i.e. on each line store the raw binary data that I read in from the shift register. So, for 8 wires, it would be 0b10011010. But this can get ugly for upto 360 wires - each line would contain 360 bytes.

Another way is to store hex values - this would just be two characters for 8 bits (9A for the above) and about 90 characters for 360 bits. This would, however, require me to read in the text - line by line - and convert the hex value to be represented in the bit-array, somehow.

So whats the best solution for this sort of problem? I need the solution to be completely "deterministic" - I can't have calls to malloc or such. They are a bit of a no-no in embedded systems from what I've read.

**SUMMARY**

I need to store large values that can't be represented by any traditional variable types. Currently I intend to store these values in a bitarray. What's the best way to store these values in a text file on an SD Card?

Comment: Why do you want to store binary data as text in the first place? There are no portability or human-readability requirements. What's wrong with e.g. `fwrite(array,sizeof(array),file)`?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong: you need to read a test sample from SD, clock it out, clock it back in and compare clocked in result with initial sample? Also, how are you going to generate a test vector (one to be stored on your SD card)? Cause, if you have a fixed set of test data, it may be easier to store the data in a simple array in program memory.

Comment: How many '1' bits do you expect simultaneously in the input? If the expected input is sparse, you'll only have to store the *positions* of the '1' bits.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are not integer values but rather bit maps; they have no arithmetic meaning.  What you are suggesting is simply a byte array of length 360/8, and not related to "large integers" at all.  However some more appropriate data structure or representation may be possible.

If the test vector is a single bit in 360, then it is both inefficient and unnecessary to store 360 bits for each vector, a value 0 to 359 is sufficient to unambiguously define each vector.  If the correct output is also a single bit, then that could also be stored as a bit index, if not then you could store it as a list of indices for each bit that should be set, with some sentinel value >=360 or <0 to indicate the end of the list.  Where most vectors contain less than fewer than 22 set bits, this structure will be more efficient that storing a 45 byte array.

From any bit index value, you can determine the address and mask of the individual wire by:

```
byte_address = base_address + bit_index / 8 ;
bit_mask = 0x01 << (bit_index % 8) ;
```

You could either test each of the 360 bits iteratively or generate a 360 bit vector on the fly from the list of bits.

I can see no need for dynamic memory allocation in this, but whether or not it is advisable in an embedded system is largely dependent on the application and target resources.  A typical AVR system has very little memory, and dynamic memory allocation carries an overhead for heap management and block alignment that you may not be able to afford.  Dynamic memory allocation is not suited in situations where hard real-time deterministic timing is required.  And in all cases you should have a well defined strategy or architecture for avoiding memory leak issues (repeatedly allocating memory that never gets released).

Comment: so when I read in the entire contents of the shift register, I should simply note down where the '1's are and discard bit array? There won't be too many '1's in the bit array so this approach would be quite beneficial.